# ECLIPSE RCP: Extend Generic Editor to add custom background image to the editor

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Following Vogella article [Developing a customer text editor for the Eclipse IDE](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseEditors/article.html#eclipse-editors) in which is defined a series of extension points to contribute to the Generic Editor, I need to contribute to Generic Editor to add a custom background image (vertical stripes).

In case contributing to Generic Editor was not possible, how to extend Generic Editor to modify the background?

What I have done with a previous editor (E4) in order to add a customized background was to include the following code inside `postConstruct(Composite parent)` method:

```java
PaletteData paletteData = new PaletteData(new RGB[] {new RGB(255,255,255), new RGB(190,190,190)});
ImageData imageData = new ImageData(MAX_PIXELS_SIZE,1,1,paletteData);
imageData.setPixels(0, 0, 3000, BackgroundPixels.stripes640Bit,  0);
backgroundImage = new Image(display, imageData);
styledText.setBackgroundImage(backgroundImage);
//Note the Part has a SytledText as the control to plot the text.
```

The result is shown in the following picture:
[image]